# Python LDAP converting objectGUID to hex string and back

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

How do I convert binary ldap attributes returned by python-ldap to a nice hex representation and back again for use in an ldap filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def guid2hexstring(val):
    s = ['\\%02X' % ord(x) for x in val]
    return ''.join(s)

guid = ldapobject.get('objectGUID', [''])[0] # 'Igr\xafb\x19ME\xb2P9c\xfb\xa0\xe2w'
guid2string(guid).replace("\\", "") # '496772AF62194D45B2503963FBA0E277'

#and back to a value you can use in an ldap search filter

guid = ''.join(['\\%s' % guid[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(guid), 2)]) # '\\49\\67\\72\\AF\\62\\19\\4D\\45\\B2\\50\\39\\63\\FB\\A0\\E2\\77'

searchfilter = ('(objectGUID=%s)' % guid)
```

Comment: I am not sure of the part after the "And back..." comment... It doesn't work for me to add some back slash and the raw objectGUID that I get out from the AD (or guid.bytes of the example above with the UUID module) can be used directly in search filter... So I don't know what was the problem in the first place... Niether why your answer get approved... I found all this miss leading...

Comment: @Richard sorry the question is vague. I needed to convert to and from the uppercase hexadecimal string without slashes for use in a URL.

Comment: AH!! You could modify your question then, as your answer wasn't make sens and make me think that I had to manipulate the raw LDAP object id in order to use it in a search query... Anyway, thanks to add a comment about that since this question was pretty old :)

Comment: This not work for me, I also had to invert the first tree bytes:
1- Original GUID from the Event Log: 
4034194C-21C1-4DC1-951D-651320577AN0
2- Divide it with backslashes: \40\34\19\4C\21\C1\4D\C1\95\1D\65\13\20\57\7A\N0
3- Invert the first 3 columns: \4C\19\34\40\C1\21\C1\4D\95\1D\65\13\20\57\7A\N0

Answer (score 4):

For the task of converting to and from hex string, you should consider the [builtin uuid module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).

```
import uuid


object_guid = 'Igr\xafb\x19ME\xb2P9c\xfb\xa0\xe2w'
guid = uuid.UUID(bytes=object_guid)

# to hex
assert guid.hex == '496772af62194d45b2503963fba0e277'

# to human-readable guid
assert str(guid) == '496772af-6219-4d45-b250-3963fba0e277'

# to bytes
assert guid.bytes == object_guid == 'Igr\xafb\x19ME\xb2P9c\xfb\xa0\xe2w'
```

Comment: Thanks but can you show me how to use uuid module to create a python ldap search filter that works?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to directly use any of the above code in order to go from a string objectGUID representation to something that would work for an ldap query.  But going on the code from @Rel and the comment from @hernan I was able to figure out how to do it.  I'm posting this in case someone like me is still puzzled about how to use the details above to formulate a search filter.  Here's what I did:

Starting from a string objectGuid (and I've borrowed the one above) I remove the hyphens.

```
guidString = '496772af-6219-4d45-b250-3963fba0e277'.replace("-","")
```

You need to reorder the characters, in pairs of characters, for the first three groupings.  I generated an order as follows:

```
newOrder = [6,7,4,5,2,3,0,1,10,11,8,9,14,15,12,13]       # the weird-ordered stuff
for i in range(16, len(guidString)): newOrder.append(i)  # slam the rest on
```

I then create a new string with the characters in the stated order:

```
guid_string_in_search_order = str.join('', [guidString[i] for i in newOrder]) 
guidSearch = ''.join(['\\%s' % str.join('',guid_string_in_search_order[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(guid_string_in_search_order), 2)])
```

Then you need to add escaped backslashes in front of each of the pairs:

```
guidSearch = ''.join(['\\%s' % str.join('',guid_string_in_search_order[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(guid_string_in_search_order), 2)])
```

That should get you a guidSearch of:

```
'\\af\\72\\67\\49\\19\\62\\45\\4d\\b2\\50\\39\\63\\fb\\a0\\e2\\77'
```

So now you make that an ldap search string:

```
search_filter = '(objectGUID={})'.format(guidSearch)
```

And there you go - ready for an ldap search.  I suspect someone with more miles clocked doing this stuff could do it in fewer steps, but at least this way you can follow what I did.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why the others are accepted answers. The bytes ARE clearly reordered with differing endianness, and further confusing as the last segment is not.

Answer (score 1):

We can use python uuid to get hex representation

```
import uuid

object_guid_from_ldap_ad = '\x1dC\xce\x04\x88h\xffL\x8bX|\xe5!,\x9b\xa9'

guid = uuid.UUID(bytes=object_guid_from_ldap_ad)
# To hex
guid.hex
# To human readable
str(guid)
# Back to bytes
assert guid.bytes == object_guid_from_ldap_ad
```

---

The answer of the second part of the question...

Search filter can be created with the original raw objectGUID out from LDAP/AD or the guid.bytes of the python UUID object, both are the same.

Example :

```
search_filter = ('(objectGUID=%s)' % object_guid_from_ldap_ad)
```

OR

```
search_filter = ('(objectGUID=%s)' % guid.bytes)
```

Then you use your search_filter in a LDAP search.